# How to select the drop down using javascript in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
<div class="inpt-slider">
  <h4 class="fdNames block">Type of Fixed Deposit</h4>
  <div class="typeOf selArrow">
    <select id="FdepType">
        <option value="Cumulative">Reinvestment (Cumulative)</option>
        <option value="Quaterly Payout">Quaterly Payout</option>
        <option value="Monthly Payout">Monthly Payout</option>
        <option value="Short Term FD">Short Term Deposit</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

How to select "Monthly Payout" in this drop down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try below solution for java:**

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.axisbank.com/retail/calculators/fd-calculator"); // URL in the browser
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); // Maximize the browser



        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("FdepType"));
        Select text = new Select(element);
        text.selectByValue("Monthly Payout");
```

Comment: I am writing the code in java. I am using javascript executor in selenium to get this.
This is the website https://www.axisbank.com/retail/calculators/fd-calculator

Comment: please try above solution

Comment: It works fine.. thanks a lot
Select text = new Select(element); -> what does this line means?

Comment: 'Select' is a class in Selenium WebDriverits used to select options in a dropdown. Objects are initialized by passing the dropdown webElement as parameter to constructor.